# Аналог object-fit: cover для андроид

Tags: css

Свойство `object-fit: cover;` работает в десктопе, также сайт "адаптиватор" показывает его работу в мобильных версиях. Однако, загрузив сайт на бюлжетном андроиде, я увидел, что фон неестественно растянут, то есть код не работает. Какие есть аналоги этому, чтобы мобильный электорат смог видеть сайт адекватно? Фрагмент css, о котором речь:

```
img.mb_bgimage{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: cover; 
    -o-fit-object: cover;
}
```

Comment: А положить картинку в фон - не вариант?

Comment: Нет, эта картинка УЖЕ на фоне. Вот так:    <body>
 
<div style='text-align: left;'>
<div class='mb_background' id='mb_background'>
   <img alt='Background' class='mb_bgimage' src='https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-D3EnHvCCFwQ/XCI44ZYxvsI/AAAAAAAABn8/-dbkc2Ob0A8OHTrmutwX4egr0jaLrr4MgCLcBGAs/s1600/oboi-eifeleva-bashnya%2B%25282%2529.webp'/>

   <div class='mb_overlay'/>
   <div class='mb_loading'/>
  </div>

Comment: Ну так и используй background-image и background-size, а не img.

Comment: У img нет фона. Точнее есть, но сама картинка - не фон.

Comment: Сделал. Исчезла полоса верткальной прокрутки (нужна только в мобильной версии). В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Код:     body{
 background:url(https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-D3EnHvCCFwQ/XCI44ZYxvsI/AAAAAAAABn8/-dbkc2Ob0A8OHTrmutwX4egr0jaLrr4MgCLcBGAs/s1600/oboi-eifeleva-bashnya%2B%25282%2529.webp) no-repeat;
 color:#fff;
 font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    -o-fit-object: cover;
    position:fixed;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:100%;
 opacity:1;
 z-index:-1;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фон надо класть в фон:

```css
html {
  background: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/iITnc.jpg) 50% 25% / cover no-repeat fixed;
}
```

Comment: Да! Это то, что нужно было. И последний вопрос (пользуясь Вашей добротой): что прописать вместо center, чтобы чуть повыше, но без изменений в вертикали?

Comment: @AAA1280350, кажется, background-position тут вообще игнорируется, так что из вариантов только контейнер двигать...

Comment: @AAA1280350, а нет, это только с center так. С двумя значениями получилось подвинуть.

Comment: Я Вам очень благодарен!